# Why does "set(a) and set(b)" vs "set(a) & set(b)" give different results in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, set-intersection

I understand that one is bitwise operation while the other is not, but how does this bitwise property affect the results of given expression.
As both should simply compare the elements in both sets and result in common elements.

`set(a) & set(b)` gives the correct answer while finding common elements in set(a) and set(b), while `set(a) and set(b)` gives wrong answer.

Python code:

```
nums2 = [9,4,9,8,4]
nums1 = [4,9,5]

a = set(nums1) and set(nums2)
b = set(nums1) & set(nums2)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Results:
 `a = {8, 9, 4}`
`b = {9, 4}`

Comment: "As both should simply compare the elements in both sets and result in common elements." No, as you're already aware, they are separate operators.  You should not expect them to behave identically; that's the whole point of them being distinct. `and` is a *logical` AND operator: it operates on the truthiness of its operands.

Comment: You are simply wrong about the what `and` does. It isn't clear *why* you believe what you believe, but it is wrong. That is the simple answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
> returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
> returned.

Thus

```py
set(nums1) and set(nums2)
```

first evaluates `set(nums1)` which is `{ 9, 4, 5 }` (which is not false - see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) and thus the expression returns `set(nums2)` i.e. `{ 8, 9, 4 }`.

By contrast, also as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
set(nums1) & set(nums2)
```

evaluates to the intersection of the two sets, which is `{ 9, 4 }`